# Angular HTTP interceptor custom preflight

Tags: angular, http, csrf, interceptor, preflight

I'm writing an application that communicates with a backend API that requires a `XSRF-TOKEN` header be set on every request. I've achieved that with the following HTTP interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  const modifiedReq = request.clone({
    headers: request.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
  });

  return next.handle(modifiedReq);
}
```

Now I need to handle the case where the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie is not yet set. In this case I will need to preflight the request that I'm sending with one that hits a specific `/csrf` endpoint on the backend API, which will return a `Set-Cookie` header to set `XSRF-TOKEN`.

As a quick and dirty test (without refactoring to remove duplicate code) I tried this:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  if (!this.cookieService.check('XSRF-TOKEN')) {
    this.apiService.csrf().subscribe(() => {
      const modifiedReq = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
      });

      return next.handle(modifiedReq);
    });
  }

  const modifiedReq = request.clone({
    headers: request.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
  });

  return next.handle(modifiedReq);
}
```

But this obviously has the consequence of an infinite loop of requests to the `/csrf` endpoint, as each HTTP request inside the interceptor is intercepted itself...

How can I achieve what I'm going for here?

Comment: I also answered this question here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66704512/7255496) - have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let the request to `/csrf` complete without intercepting it:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

  if (request.url === '/csrf') {
    return next.handle(request);
  }

  if (!this.cookieService.check('XSRF-TOKEN')) {
    this.apiService.csrf().subscribe(() => {
      const modifiedReq = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
      });

      return next.handle(modifiedReq);
    });
  }

  const modifiedReq = request.clone({
    headers: request.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
  });

  return next.handle(modifiedReq);
}
```