# Intercepting HTTP request with a preflight, and then executing the original request

Tags: angular, typescript, http, observable

I'm trying to write the following Angular HTTP interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  if (request.url.endsWith('/csrf')) {
    return next.handle(request);
  }

  if (!this.cookieService.check('XSRF-TOKEN')) {
    const csrfRequest = new HttpRequest('GET', environment.apiUrl + '/csrf');

    return next.handle(csrfRequest).pipe(
      // something here to retry the original request?
    );
  }

  const modifiedReq = request.clone({
    headers: request.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
  });

  return next.handle(modifiedReq);
}
```

The basic idea is that if the browser doesn't have the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie set, we need to preflight the request with a call to `/csrf` to first set that cookie. Then we need to do the original request.

The above interceptor does successfully do the `/csrf` call if the cookie is not set. What I'm struggling with is how to also do the original HTTP request AFTER that `/csrf` call.

I feel like it can be achieved by observable piping, but I don't have a lot of observables knowledge and looking at the RxJS docs has left me even more confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this `/csrf`-request inside interceptor via `HttpClient` (it should be injected in interceptor) and transform it into modified request handler observable. It will look like:

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  if (request.url.endsWith('/csrf')) {
    return next.handle(request);
  }
  
  return of(this.cookieService.check('XSRF-TOKEN'))
            .pipe(
                switchMap((hasToken: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> => {
                    if (hasToken) {
                        const modifiedReq = request.clone({
                          headers: request.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
                        });

                        return next.handle(modifiedReq); 
                    }
                    
                    return httpClient.get(environment.apiUrl + '/csrf')
                                .pipe(
                                    switchMap((): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> => {
                                        const modifiedReq = request.clone({
                                          headers: request.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
                                        });

                                        return next.handle(modifiedReq); 
                                    })
                                );
                })
            );
}
```